# Sort by average value in One To Many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following 3 relationships:

User:

```
public function posts () {
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
}

public function ratings () {
    return $this->hasMany(Rating::class)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
}
```

Post:

```
public function user () {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function ratings () {
    return $this->hasMany(Rating::class)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
}
```

Rating:

```
public function user () {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function post () {
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
}
```

A user can create a post and other users can rate posts basically.

In my controller I want to be able to sort the posts based on 3 filters, created date, updated date **and top rated posts by average rating**.

I have solved the first two filter options with the following code:

```
return Post::with(['user'])->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(15)->onEachSide(1);
```

and

```
return Post::with(['user'])->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')->paginate(15)->onEachSide(1);
```

I have however no idea how to sort the posts by average ratings. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Also, would it be possible to prevent posts with only one rating to be in the top of the list, maybe require the post to have at least X ratings before it's counted?

Comment: Can users rate other users?

Comment: @CaddyDZ Nope, users can only rate on posts, any user can rate on any post.

Comment: Then you have an extra meaningless relationship on the user model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `ratings` relationship on the User model since users can not be rated

Then pass a closure to the `withCount` method to order by ratings using the SQL `coalesce` function via raw SQL statement on the DB facade

```php
return Post::with(['user'])->withCount(['ratings as average' => function ($query) {
            $query->select(\DB::raw('coalesce(avg(column_in_ratings_table), 0)'));
}])->orderByDesc('average')->get();
```

> would it be possible to prevent posts with only one rating to be in the top of the list?

Yes, using [query scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#query-scopes)

However, please note that you can't ask multiple questions on one post in Stack Overflow see [this meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267058/how-to-handle-a-question-that-asks-many-things)

Your question might be flagged as `too broad`

Hope this helps